# Ruby Gem: Contacts for importing fails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, contacts

I have the gem working nicely for gmail on my mac. I switch to production and the stuff stops working.

Also, Blackbook doesn't work at all with gmail accounts. Any suggestions for a solid way too import contacts in Ruby on Rails?

** pls note that Ubuntu is running 1.8.6 vs 1.8.7 on my Mac. I wonder if that is causing different bahavior...

Answer (score 0):

try this one
http://raveendran.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/contacts-ruby-gem-import-contacts-from-gmail-yahoo-hotmail/